# Rendering NumberLong in a single field when using mongosh

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongosh

I have a collection `c` in DB named `ftest` in MongoDB. A document has been created in that collection with a NumberLong field this way:

```
db.c.insert({x: NumberLong("1")})
```

I get the content of the collection this way (based in [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77665987/mongosh-providing-output-to-eval-as-valid-json-syntax)):

```
$ mongosh mongodb://localhost:27017/ftest --eval 'JSON.stringify(db.c.find().toArray(), null, " ")' --quiet
[
 {
  "_id": "6580316ed1c208e8c6059954",
  "x": {
   "low": 1,
   "high": 0,
   "unsigned": false
  }
 }
]
```

Comparing with how mongo legacy shell works:

```
$ mongo mongodb://localhost:27017/ftest --eval 'JSON.stringify(db.c.find().toArray(), null, " ")' --quiet
[
 {
  "_id": {
   "$oid": "6580316ed1c208e8c6059954"
  },
  "x": {
   "$numberLong": "1"
  }
 }
]
```

So:

- What's the meaning of `low`, `high` and `unsigned`? Are they documented somewhere?
- Can they be converted to a single field in a similar way mongo legacy shell does?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `EJSON.stringify()` [EJSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejson) instead of `JSON`

Comment: For reference, the form you mentioned is named MongoDB extended JSON. You can find the official MongoDB documentation from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @WernfriedDomscheit feedback, using

```
$ mongosh mongodb://localhost:27017/ftest --eval 'EJSON.stringify(db.c.find().toArray(), null, " ")' --quiet
```

I get

```
[
 {
  "_id": {
   "$oid": "6580316ed1c208e8c6059954"
  },
  "x": 1
 }
]
```

which cover perfectly my use case.